# Motion sensor switch replacing regular switch for laundry room light - what went wrong?

Tags: electrical, wiring, switch

I have a laundry room with a single ceiling light fixture operated by a single pole wall switch. I removed the switched and saw a single black wire that was spliced and I saw an orange wire tied to several other wires with a wire cap. I cut the single spliced black wire and usung a 3 connector wago I inserted the 2 black wires and the new motion sensor (2 black wires) using one black wire into the wago connector and the remaining black wire with the orange wire andf the other wires and used a wire cap to secure them all. I did get power however the motion sensor on off switch would not turn on the light. Confused now and need help.

Comment: a) Colors are a little unusual - is this US/Canada or someplace else? b) Pictures of the switch box would help a lot c) What is the make/model of the motion sensor?

Comment: this is the USA. I'm headed over to the work site now and will take pictures and post it and the motion sensor wiring as well.

Comment: Orange might be 100% correct _if_ it's individual wires in conduit... Pics will help. Also, please be sure to indicate both ends of the black wire you cut.

Comment: I got the issue resolved. very simple I needed to ground the green wire to the electrical box and connect my blue wire to the other neutral white wires. I'm all done and good to go.

Comment: What make and model is this motion sensor?